# Replacing hyphen with space, but space hyphen space should not be replaced

Tags: php

can we replace all hyphen with blank spaces but if space is followed by hypen and then another space it should not be removed, for example if i get "to-be-or-not - to-be" output should be "to be or not - to be" .is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$input` is your input string, try this:

```
$output = preg_replace('/([^ ])-([^ ])/', '\\1 \\2', $input);
echo $output;
```

The regular expression means *one non-space character `[^ ]`, followed by a hyphen and followed by another non-space character*, and replace patterns means *the first non-space character matched `\\1`, followed by a space, followed by the second non-space character matched `\\2`*.

Answer (score 3):

This would work too ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mFPTYx))

```
echo preg_replace('(\b-\b)', ' ', 'to-be-or-not - to be');
```

The `\b` matches word boundaries. Note that if you also need to match dashes at the beginning or end of a string, this will not work, e.g. `-foo-bar-` will be `-foo bar-`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the regex `/(?! )-(?! )/`.